# Calculate maximum affordable property value for given capital, taking stamp duty into account

Tags: finance, percentages

I want to calculate maximum affordable property value for given capital, taking stamp duty into account

Assume the only house-purchasing costs are the house price plus (UK) stamp duty.

For any given property the TotalCost is therefore the SalePrice plus the StampDuty.

Stamp duty is currently banded as follows:

| From | To | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| £0 | £124,999 | Zero |
| £125,000 | £249,999 | 2% |
| £250,000 | £924,999 | 3% |
| £925,000 | £1,499,999 | 5% |
| Remaining amount (above £1,500,000) |  | 2% |

To calculate the StampDuty (and therefore the TotalCost) we can perform a calculation which can be described using the following Excel formula (assuming the SalePrice is in A1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1>{125000;250000;925000;1500000}), A1-{125000;250000;925000;1500000}, {0.02;0.03;0.05;0.02})
```

My question is this: How can I perform the inverse calculation?

In other words:

> The cost equation consists of three terms and looks like this: `SalePrice + Tax = TotalCost`
>
> I have shown, above, how to work out the `Tax` (and therefore the `TotalCost`) from a given `SalePrice`.
>
> But how do I do the inverse; work out the `Tax` (and therefore the `SalePrice`) from a given `TotalCost`?

Answer does not have to be in the form of an Excel formula.

Comment: I dont think you formula is right. For instance the 3% for $125,000$ to $249,999:$ The tax for this interval is just $(249999-125000+1)\cdot 0.03=125000\cdot 0.03=3750$ So for every $A_1\geq 249,999$ you have to pay the tax $3750$.

Comment: Good spot.  My percentages got mangled during table editing.  I have now updated the table to hold the intended values.

Comment: Are you sure of the SUMPRODUCT formula? For a sale price of $300000$, if I understand correctly, the tax should be $$125000\cdot 0.02 +50000\cdot 0.03=4000$$ where $125000$ is the part of the price subject to the $2\%$ tax and $50000$ is the part of the price subject to the $3\%$ tax.  However, it seems that your  formula uses $A1-125000$ for the part on which to calculate the $2\%$, so in this example it would give $$175000\cdot 0.02 +50000\cdot 0.03=5000$$

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not completely sure.  The formula was found on the internet and tested against some online calculators, which gave the same results as I got, for the small set of numbers I tried.  However, it is possible that there is a mistake.  I will investigate.

Comment: Ok! Just for clarity, is my example of calculation correct? In other words, should the stamp duty be calculated by dividing the price in different parts, each subject to a different percentage?

Comment: Yes - your understanding is correct. To be explicit, the calculation should be: `125000⋅0+125000⋅0.02+50000⋅0.03=4000`.  I see the point you're making and it appears that there is no upper bound being set, i.e. the first 0.02 is applied to the full amount above 125k, rather than just the band between 125k and 250k.  To counter this, I wonder if the final array should contain offsets, i.e. `{0.02;0.01;0.02;-0.03}`?  However, this formula appears to be widely circulated on the internet, so I'm wary about changing it without understanding it a bit better.

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected.  The original calculation *is* correct, and the tax on 300,000 *should* be 5,000.  I have just put this figure into the government calculator at https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/calculate-stamp-duty-land-tax and this is the figure it gives.

Answer (score 1):

You have given us the price limits and tax rates. They are:

$$
pricelimits=[124999,249999,924999,1499999]\\
taxrates=[0,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.02]
$$

You first need to find the tax limits for the intervals. They are:

$$
taxlimits=[0,2500,22750,51500]
$$

This means that for the values in the price limits, you pay the corresponding values in the tax limits.

Now you need to find the total cost limits, which are just price limits and tax limits added together. We have:

$$
totalcost=[ 124999,  252499,  947749, 1551499]
$$

Then,

1. Find the first number in the total costs that your cost is less than. If you paid £400000, that number is £252499.
2. Find the surplus cost, i.e., the difference between the value you got in step 1 and the total cost you paid. Again, for £400000, that is £147501.
3. The tax on the sale is the sum of the tax limit value corresponding to the total cost that you found in step 1 and surplus price divided by (1 + the corresponding tax rate) and multiplied by the tax rate. For £400000, you get £2500+£147501*.03/1.03=£6796.1
4. Now that you have the tax, just take the difference between the total cost and the tax. If you paid £400000 for a house, the sale price is £393203.9 and £6796.1 is the tax.

[image]

The vertical lines correspond to the breakpoints due to the changes in the tax rate.

Here is the Python code. It is very unoptimised, but you don't need much optimisation for this calculation. Just insert the tax for which you want to find the price at the last line, if you use python.

```
limits=np.asarray([125000,250000,925000,1500000])-1

tax_rate=np.asarray([0,.02,.03,.05])

def limit_finder():
    limit_stamp=[]
    for i in range(len(limits)):
        if i==0:
            limit_stamp.append(0)
        else:
            limit_stamp.append((limits[i]-limits[i-1])*tax_rate[i])
    return np.cumsum(limit_stamp)

def tax_finder(price):
    limit_stamp=limit_finder()
    true_limits=limit_stamp+limits
    if price>true_limits[-1]:
        price_f_surplus=price-true_limits[-1]
        return limit_stamp[-1]+price_f_surplus*.02/1.02
    for i in range(len(true_limits)):
        if price<true_limits[i] or price==true_limits[i]:
            price_surplus=price-true_limits[i-1]
            return limit_stamp[i-1]+price_surplus*tax_rate[i]/(1+tax_rate[i])

print(tax_finder(1550000))
```

Comment: This seems like a good and thorough answer, but I will need a bit of time to process and digest it.  I'll get back to you once I've had a chance to work through it in more detail.

Comment: Very thorough answer.  Thank you.  Bounty awarded!

Comment: @HappyDog Thank you. I thought you forgot about this :) I'd be happier if you accept the answer as well.

Comment: I've deliberately left it unaccepted for now, as I've only reviewed it through a close reading and not had a chance to implement a test-case yet.  I'll come back and accept it once I've verified it more formally.